# I want to convert array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to convert:

from

```
['firstName','lastName','gender']
```

to

```
0: {title: "firstName"}
1: {title: "lastName"}
2: {title: "gender"}
```

in JavaScript

Comment: Try `['firstName','lastName','gender'].map(e => ({title: e}))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply use `forEach()` loop which is the easiest way:

```js
var arr = ['firstName','lastName','gender'];

let res = [];
arr.forEach((item) => res.push({title: item}));
console.log(res);
```

Just to build your knowledge in Array operations you can also use `reduce()`:

```js
var arr = ['firstName','lastName','gender'];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({title: item});
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to get the desired output:

```js
const data = ['firstName','lastName','gender'];

const result = data.map(name => ({ title: name }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.I hope it will helps you.

```js
var arr = ['firstName','lastName','gender']

var jsonObj = {};
for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    jsonObj['title' +(i+1) ] = arr[i];
}
console.log(jsonObj)
```